# Alternative design to master-detail grid rows

Tags: master-details

I have a web application with a Master-detail grid I did while back that uses dynamically generated tabs if a particular service was performed as the details row. I'm going to have to change the way I'm displaying the data since the previous application was created using server controls (planning on using jQuery UI instead). What is the best alternative to display the detail information? Perhaps a modal pop-up?

[image]

Comment: Please : no _modal_ popups. They are the most obnoxious and intrusive things in a user interface. Use them sparingly and reserve them for error messages that require immediate action by the user without which the app can't continue in any meaningful manner.

Comment: If I understand this...the user is clicking ona Job row, and then we need to show the details of the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've got job ids listed on a map makes me think of a real estate site or hotel site...things located on a map, that I want to drill down and learn more.

In either case, the site usually has the map+list on one page, and  clicking on a particular result sends you to a separate details page.

Real Estate example: [Zillow.com](http://www.zillow.com/homes/iowa-city,-ia_rb/)

Hotel example: [Marriott.com](http://marriott.com)

Comment: Ah...the inspiration I was looking for. Thanks these are good alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvfyCz.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Could you do it kind of like an email client (eg Apple Mail, Outlook) where you've got a list of things on the left, and you click on it to get the details on the right?

Also, if you have all of the job locations shown on a map, do you HAVE to have a separate list?

Comment: +1 for providing another idea with sample. Thanks again!